# stop the user from entering an input after the 10th input

Tags: java

I'm very new to java and I'm wondering on how to stop the user from entering an input after the 10th. (inputs are separated by space)

sample output would be:

> Please type 10 temperatures in Celsius: 30 12 20.5 ..
>
> Temperatures in Celsius:         30.0 12.0 20.5 …
>
> Temperatures in Fahrenheit:  86.0 53.6 68.9 …

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class array {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        double [] a = new double [10];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please type 10 temperatures in Celsius: ");
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++)
            a[j] = sc.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Temperatures in Celsius:  ");
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

        System.out.print("\nTemperatures in Fahrenheit:  ");
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) 
            a[i] = a[i]*1.8+32;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
               System.out.printf("%.1f ", a[i]);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: please learn to (almost) always use curly braces with your loops :)  `for(...) { code }` instead of `for(...) code`

Comment: From console, you cannot do this... only check for fewer than 10 inputs and display an error message if that's not the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible, because input is provided from a terminal/shell, and this terminal usually reads input linewise. You have to do much more low level coding to handle scenarios like these.

Just output an error if the users enters more than 10 values and let him enter them again.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel is correct, with your current setup its not quite possible. You could do it, if you're ok with the console looking a bit different. This requires more 'Enter' presses, and moves each temp to its own line.

> Enter 10 temps:
>
> Enter 1: [user input here]
>
> Enter 2: [user input here]
>
> etc etc

```
System.out.println("Enter 10 temps");
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    System.out.print("Enter " + i + ":");
    a[i-1] = scanner.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can do some thing like this evry time put a number fo 10 times for each will print temperture in Celsius and in Fahrenheit

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {

    int counter = 0;
    double[] a = new double[10];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please type temperatures in Celsius: ");

    while(counter < 10){
        a[counter] = sc.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Temperatures in Celsius:  " + a[counter]);

    double tF = a[counter]*1.8 + 32;
    System.out.println("Temperatures in Fahrenheit:  " + tF);

    counter++;
    }
}
```